# Javascript 'while' loop causing browser to crash

Tags: javascript, while-loop, crash

I have a 'search and highlight' function that looks through each node in an element and highlights each instance of the keyword. Within this function I have used a while(true) that seems to be causing the browsers to either crash or lag! Are there any alternatives to this while loop? 
Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

```
console.log(keyword);
                if (keyword != "") {
                    SearchResultCount = 0;
                    currSelected = -1;
                    if (element) {
                        if (element.nodeType == 3) {
                            while (true) {
                                var value = element.nodeValue; // Search for keyword in text node
                                var idxSensitive = value.indexOf(keyword);
                                var idxInsensitive = value.toLowerCase()
                                        .indexOf(keyword);

                                if ((idxInsensitive < 0)
                                        && (idxSensitive < 0))
                                    break; // not found, abort
                                else if ((idxInsensitive >= 0)
                                        && (idxSensitive < 0))
                                    var idx = idxInsensitive;
                                else if ((idxSensitive >= 0)
                                        && (idxInsensitive < 0))
                                    var idx = idxSensitive;

                                var span = document.createElement("span");
                                var text = document.createTextNode(value
                                        .substr(idx, keyword.length));
                                span.appendChild(text);
                                span.setAttribute("class",
                                        "highlightedText");
                                span.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
                                span.style.color = "black";
                                text = document.createTextNode(value
                                        .substr(idx + keyword.length));
                                element.deleteData(idx, value.length - idx);
                                var next = element.nextSibling;
                                element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, next);
                                element.parentNode.insertBefore(text, next);
                                element = text;
                                SearchResultCount++; // update the counter
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

While loops need a `false` condition or a `break` to end. All I see is a `while (true)` which will never evaluate to `false`. Since you have a never ending loop, it causes your browser to crash. Though it should `break` if `idxSensitive` and `idxInsensitive` are negative numbers, any other value will keep the loop running forever.

Comment: I am so sorry I pasted in my attempt at fixing it! I have edited the post with the correct code now. I have a 'break' if no result is found, do I need another 'break' somewhere else?

Comment: It should break if no result is found, but if a result is found, the loop will continue forever. Why are you looping in the first place?

Comment: Well multiple instances of 'keyword' will usually be found, and each will be highlighted, so the while is present just so it checks the whole text element, I basically need a way to tell it to break out of the loop once it reaches the end of the text element, I just don't know how? Is there a way to count to number of words in 'element' where 'element' is the body of text?

Comment: Yes. Once if have just the text as a String, you can do this: `element.split(' ').length`. This will give you the amount of words in a body of text. What that does is it splits the string, at each space, into an array and then returns the length of that array.

Comment: After that you can just run a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop to stop the loop after you've checked all the words. `for (var i = 0; i < element.split(' ').length; i++) {...}` Be advised, I'm using `element` as my variable name, but the value of `element` in your code probably isn't actually a String. Whatever variable you use for this needs to be the actual text from the element as a String.

Answer (score 0):

To loop something forever(instead of while(true)), you can use:

```
setTimeout(function, 1);

//Or

for (var i = 0; i < Infinity; i++) {
    //Code goes here
}
```